# Get return value in QML from Python method

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I'm trying to call a Python method from QML and use the return value.

QML receives undefined, from the Python method.

When passed back to Python it is just an empty string.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class InPython(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(str, )
    def login(self, Login):
        print(Login)
        return "a"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load('Main.qml')
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    inPython = InPython()
    context.setContextProperty("loginManger", inPython)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800;
    height: 600;

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.margins: 3
        spacing: 3
        Column {
            spacing: 20
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            TextField {
                id: login
                objectName: "login"
                placeholderText: qsTr("Login")
                focus: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                onAccepted: {
                    btnSubmit.clicked()
                }
            }

            Button {
                id: btnSubmit
                objectName: "btnSubmit"
                text: qsTr("Login")
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                onClicked: {
                    var a = loginManger.login(login.text);
                    console.log(a);
                    loginManger.login(a); // Python recieves ''
                    if (a === "a"){
                        login.text = "SUCCESS"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You also need to tell what you are returning from your method (pay attention to the `result` in the pyqtslot decorator:

```
class InPython(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(str, result=str)  # also works: @pyqtSlot(QVariant, result=QVariant)
    def login(self, Login):
        print(Login)
        return "a"
```

> result – the type of the result and may be a Python type object or a
>   string that specifies a C++ type. This may only be given as a keyword
>   argument.

[Documentation about @pyqtslot](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) (and the `result` parameter)